# error de sintaxis en lógica booleana

Tags: python, python-3.x

estoy realizando unos ejercicios de un libro y al transcribir este código de el libro me da error de sintaxis en la linea 6.

```
mes = int(input("Dame un mes: "))

if 1 <= mes <= 3:
    print("invierno.")
else:
    if mes == 4 or mes == 5 == or mes == 6:
        print("primavera")
    else:
        if not (mes <7 or 9 < mes):
            print("verano")
        else:
            if not (mes != 10 and mes != 11 and mes != 12):
                print("otoño")
            else:
                print("ningun año tiene {0} meses.".format(mes))
```

Seguro que es una tonteria pero no hay manera de hacerlo funcionar, el error es el siguiente:

```
    if mes == 4 or mes == 5 == or mes == 6:
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Es solo un error tipográfico, se te ha colado (a ti o en el libro) un `==` de sobra después del 5, debe ser `if mes == 4 or mes == 5 or mes == 6:`. Por cierto, bienvenido a [es.so] Javier. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

```
else:
    if mes == 4 or mes == 5  or mes == 6:
```

Comment: Procura siempre indicar cómo deberían usar tu código en la solución del problema. Tirar un fragmento de código sin más es igual a preguntar tirando un fragmento de código sin más.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la mejor manera de implementarlo es la siguiente:

```
mes = int(input("Proporciona el mes del año (1-12):"))
estacion = None
if mes == 1 or mes == 2 or mes == 12:
    estacion = "Invierno"
elif mes == 3 or mes == 4 or mes == 5:
    estacion = "Primavera" 
elif mes == 6 or mes == 7 or mes == 8:
    estacion = "Verano"
elif mes == 9 or mes == 10 or mes == 11:
    estacion = "Otoño"
else:
    estacion = "Mes incorrecto"    

print("estación", estacion, "para el mes", mes)
```

En esa linea que mencionas, el error está en que, hay una igualdad doble demás, tu código dice:

`if mes == 4 or mes == 5 == or mes == 6:`

y justo antes del segundo `or` hay una igualdad doble(==), si se quita:

`if mes == 4 or mes == 5 or mes == 6:`

El código quedaría bien, y funcionará perfectamente.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Pues si, muchas gracias, estoy aprendiendo por mi cuenta y no encontraba el error, aunque lo tenia delante de los ojos